# Huawei y530 internal storage problem after rooting with TowelRoot

Tags: root-access, huawei

My phone had a bug that said: "Insufficient internal storage", so I tried to solve this rooting with TowelRoot, but when I did things became worse... Now, it seems I can't access internal storage.. if I try to save anything (image, music, etc) to it, it crashes, it just says: "Unable to save file, try again later" if its from WhatsApp, if I try with chrome it closes, if I try with the computer it stays some time trying to copy the file then it says it cannot do it.
After this, I did a Hard Reset (power + up volume buttons), but that didn't do it... What can I so now to access the internal storage and be able to save files again?

Answer (score -1):

Try installing  [SuperSU from google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu). *SuperSU* has an option to **unroot**. Try multiple times (if it doesn't work once) and reset the phone this fixes the internal memory problem.